# LHS and Markdown: Codeblocks

Tags: haskell, markdown, literate-programming

I happen to really like Markdown (probably because of SO) and I like programming in Haskell. I have recently discovered [Literate Haskell](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Literate_programming) (LHS) and I want to use Markdown and LHS together. Let me give you this dumb example:

```
Crazy Literate Haskell
======================

This is an example of some literate Haskell Code:

> module Main where

Look at that IO Monad work:

> main = return 2 >>= print

Wasn't that cool?
```

That is an example of a literate haskell file written to be parsed by Markdown later. However, I want the code to actually appear in html code blocks and without the > before them. Therefore I cannot merely indent all of the code lines by four because that would produce the markdown that you see above. Basically, I want the html to come out like this:

```
<h1>Crazy Literate Haskell</h1>

<p>This is an example of some literate Haskell Code:</p>

<pre><code>module Main where
</code></pre>

<p>Look at that IO Monad work:</p>

<pre><code>main = return 2 &gt;&gt;= print
</code></pre>

<p>Wasn't that cool?</p>
```

The thing to notice is that it has no > symbols. How would I do that?

Comment: Now obviously I could throw the .lhs file through a sed 's_^> _    _' but I don't really want to. I would rather some built in function that I did not know about.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/).  It has a [markdown+lhs](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#literate-haskell-support) mode for using markdown in literal Haskell files, and if you don't like the html it produces, there is [an api](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc) for modifying the document structure.

Install it with

```
cabal install pandoc
```

Comment: Robert, The html pasted here http://hpaste.org/fastcgi/hpaste.fcgi/raw?id=29029 is the result of cutting your markdown and pasting it to `pandoc` with 

    `pbpaste | pandoc -r markdown+lhs -w html -s | pbcopy`

Just in case you take up Haskell blog-writing ... note that you *can* ask `pandoc` to write `literate html` with bird-tracks:    `pbpaste | pandoc -r markdown+lhs -w html+lhs | pbpaste`  -- then you'd get this:   http://hpaste.org/fastcgi/hpaste.fcgi/view?id=29030
The html is oddly, but legally, formatted; you can get rid of this by passing it through `tidy`.

Comment: That is an excellent answer, both Dave and applicative. Thankyou, this was exactly what I was looking for. Marking as answer.

Comment: And to prepare it for publishing on StackOverflow (as normal markdown, without .lhs tricks), one can do `pandoc --from markdown+lhs --to markdown`! (Only the HTML-style comments in the source markdown get treated in a wrong way. I use them for storing Emacs variables at the end of the file.)